# Sample phrase "Cancel my service using FieldService" was not classified as a INCancelWorkoutIntent intent

Tags: siri

The warning I get via email after last build was uploaded was:

> Sample phrase "Cancel my service using FieldService" was not classified as a INCancelWorkoutIntent intent.

Related info.plist file looks like this:

[image]

**What to do to fix that issue?**

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Any news @BartłomiejSemańczyk? Having the same problem here...